trouble with rescaling function
I have a table t
t:([] x: 1 2 3 4 5; y: 5.1 2.4 3.3 4.5 1.5);
x y  
-----
1 5.1
2 2.4
3 3.3
4 4.5
5 1.5

and I'm trying to rescale the x and y rows of t such that the larger one becomes 1 and the other takes the value ceiling max(x;y)%min(x;y) as:
rescaledUnits:{[t]
    t:update l:max(x;y), s:min(x;y) from t;
    t:update a:ceiling l%s, ones:1 from t;
    t:update uc:ones, up:a where x>=y from t;
    t:update uc:a, up:ones where x<y from t;
    t
 };

but on calling it I get
show rescaledUnits[t]

q)

'length
    t:update a:ceiling l%s, one:1 from t;
    t:update uc:one, up:a where x>=y from t;
      ^
    t:update uc:a, up:one where x<y from t;


How do i fix the above function?

Your update statements are wrong
q)t:([] x: 1 2 3 4 5; y: 5.1 2.4 3.3 4.5 1.5)
q)t
x y
-----
1 5.1
2 2.4
3 3.3
4 4.5
5 1.5
q)rescaledUnits
{[t]
    t:update l:max(x;y), s:min(x;y) from t;
    t:update a:ceiling l%s, ones:1 from t;
    t:update uc:ones, up:a from t where x>=y ;
    t:update uc:a, up:ones from t where x<y ;
    t
 }
q)rescaledUnits[t]
x y   l   s   a ones uc up
--------------------------
1 5.1 5.1 1   6 1    6  1
2 2.4 2.4 2   2 1    2  1
3 3.3 3.3 3   2 1    2  1
4 4.5 4.5 4   2 1    2  1
5 1.5 5   1.5 4 1    1  4
q)

The where clause comes at the end. Q-SQL queries have the form of
select <cols> <by> from T<exp> <where>
You can read about it here
https://code.kx.com/q4m3/9_Queries_q-sql/

It's easy to see that where x>y the larger one is x (and will need to become 1), max(x;y) is x and min(x;y) is y.
Everything is mirrored where x<y: the larger one is y (and will become 1), max(x;y) is y and min(x;y) is x.
So there's no need to compute auxiliary columns:
rescaledUnits:{[t]
  ii:exec i from t where x>y;
  t:update x:1,y:`float$ceiling x%y from t where i in ii;
  update x:ceiling y%x,y:1.0 from t where not i in ii } 

